# Installing bcrypt with node gyp behind proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, node-gyp

I am using in my nodejs application `bcrypt` npm package for authentication/crypting passwords. Issue is with the proxy. As proxy is blocking installation of pre-build binaries:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.0 and node@8.12.0 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error connect ECONNREFUSED 10.254.3.15:443
```

I have configured npm proxy with:

`npm config set registry http://proxy-url`

But as it seems node-pre-gyp installs dependencies from somewhere else, it does not use proxy and thus fails. All other npm packages get installed fine. I tried to searching for required pre-build libraries but without any concrete solution. Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

> Follow these step

create **binding.gyp** file manually under the path C:\Users\Administrator with following content:

```
{
"targets": [
{
"target_name": "binding",
"sources": [ "build/Release/binding.node" ]
}
]
}
```

After that, I run **node-gyp rebuild** command and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with node-gyp unable to connect (during npm install bcrypt). While usually npm is using http-proxy variable to setup packages, gyp is using the proxy variable.

`npm config set proxy "http://user:password@proxyUrl:port"`

worked fine for me.